# Get path of file uploaded to Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a Python web application that runs locally in a web browser for interface convenience, processes files that a user selects, and saves processed data. I need to add the feature that creates a new subdirectory in the same folder where the file was selected (i.e., if the file is path/fname.txt, I need to create path/fname/ where I can put processed data). How do I access this path to the file?

In other projects I have asked for the path separately, but that's clunky and I'd rather not make the user do this extraneous step for each file.

```
@app.route('/getthefile', methods=['POST'])
def getthefile():
    file = request.files['myfile']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    new_path = os.path.abspath(filename)
    # gives me the wrong path
```

Comment: how did you resolve this?

Comment: @Navi Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66729597/6244201) be of help?

Comment: page not found@GitauHarrison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to not expose unnecessary information about the client's system, only the filename is sent with the HTTP request.  The full path is not sent.  Take a look at an [HTTP multipart/form-data request](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2):

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name"

Larry
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

... contents of file1.txt ...
--AaB03x--
```

As you can see, information is pretty minimal.  The path is not provided.

Similarly, the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) only allows access the filename.

So unfortunately, you won't be able to get the full path from a file input.